# Nodejs not writting to log file in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I am trying to log HTTP requests to a `.log` file.

i create and write it like so.

```
const accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'logger.log'), { flags: 'a' });
```

and i write to it via a middleware.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const start = process.hrtime()
  res.on('finish', () => {            
      const durationInMilliseconds = getDurationInMilliseconds (start);     accessLogStream.write(`${req.method}\t\t${req.originalUrl}\t\t${res.statusCode}\t\t${Math.trunc(durationInMilliseconds).toLocaleString()}ms\n`)
  })
  next()
})
```

on hitting `/logs` endpoint i read the data in file

```
app.get('/api/v1/on-covid-19/logs?',(req,res) => {
    fs.readFile('./logger.log', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // line by line
        res.format({
            'text/plain': function () {
              res.send(data)}})
    }) 
});
```

The above functionality is able to write to my `logger.log` file in devt but does not update `logger.log` file in production on `heroku`. What am i not doing?

Hitting the `/logs` endpoint returns an empty `data` string in production.

Comment: #Mats_invasion Did you solve your problem with @maniacalrobot answer?

Comment: No, but i understand @maniacalrobot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku Dynos use an [Ephemeral Filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), this is a read/write filesystem which is only available for as long as the Dyno is running, as soon as a Dyno is restarted or stopped (which will happen at least every 24 hours), any changes that were written to the filesystem will be destroyed. When a new Dyno is started, the Dyno will have the same filesystem that was compiled when your application was built during deployment.

For your applications logs, it's highly recommended that you use a [logging addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/categories/logging) to stream and store logs in a dedicated service. If you have to stores logs as files, you will need to use a mass storage system such as AWS S3.